# Disqus comment moderation inside Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, disqus

Disqus comments can be integrated with Django using [django-disqus](https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus), but I haven't found any way to **moderate** those comments within Django/Django Admin. Moderation has to happen through the Disqus dashboard.

Are there any projects providing Disqus comment moderation in Django? Or even useful Disqus API libraries? I made a quick search without results and I don't want to begin to work on something that already exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, no tools are available to integrate Disqus admin in your Django Admin. You cannot even add it in an `iframe` because disqus.com denied request from `iframe`.

However, [there is an official API](https://disqus.com/api/docs/) which allows some operations on posts and users, you can build your own moderator tools maybe (by keeping in mind you are limited to *1,000 requests per hour*). You could even create an open-source application, if you are this sort of kind person :)